# Animate layer.mask (not the .path of a shape layer)

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

It's relatively easy to animate the path of a `CAShapeLayer`.

( Great article on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36461202/294884 )

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = .. some bezier
... CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
```

But is it actually possible to animate layer.mask in a UIView?

Recall that

1. The actual layer.mask of a UIView will actually mask subviews of the UIView.
2. a CAShapeLayer with a path does not mask subviews of the UIView; it just masks itself and creates a pretty picture there on that view.

Can you animate a UIView's .layer.mask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I created a whole series of "wipe" transition animations doing that. You just make the `CAShapeLayer` the mask, and animate the path of that mask's shape layer. (In my case I animated the start or end property of the path.)

The thread is pretty old at this point, and the code is written in Objective-C, but here is a SO thread explaining how to do create a "clock wipe" animation using a `CAShapeLayer` as a layer mask.

[How do you achieve a "clock wipe"/ radial wipe effect in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409212/how-do-you-achieve-a-clock-wipe-radial-wipe-effect-in-ios/22409309#22409309)

Comment: Ah I've got it now @DuncanC !  thanks!  I see what you're saying.  If you set the .mask of the view as a layer - and you animate that layer - it apparently "knows" that means to animate the .mask of the view!  Thanks!