# Clip a UIView with a circle path Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, path, clip

I'm trying to clip my camera preview (UIView) inside a circle path but the mask I seems to not clip my view.

[image]

```
        let preview = cameraController!.previewLayer
        preview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        _view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        


        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: _view.frame.size.width/2, y: _view.frame.size.height/2),
                                radius: _view.frame.size.width/2.5,
                                startAngle: CGFloat(0).toRadians(),
                                endAngle: CGFloat(360).toRadians(),
                                clockwise: false)
        
        path.reversing()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
        preview.layer.mask = shapeLayer
        preview.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        preview.clipsToBounds = true
        
        _view.addSubview(preview)
```

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the set up was fine, just changed a few things to get it working:

```
func maskPreview()
{
    // No change from your code
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2,
                                               y: view.frame.size.height/2),
                            radius: view.frame.size.width/2.5,
                            startAngle: CGFloat(0).toRadians(),
                            endAngle: CGFloat(360).toRadians(),
                            clockwise: false)
    
    // Removed this, not sure it was needed
    // Add it back if needed
    //path.reversing()
    
    // No change
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    
    // This should not be transparent since we need
    // the camera preview to be seen through here
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    
    // No change
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
    
    // No change
    previewView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    
    // You do not need to add the shape layer as a sublayer
    // after defining it as your mask
    // previewView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    
    // No change
    previewView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

End result

[image: Mask Camera Preview Circle Path UIBezierPath CAShapeLayer Clip UIView Preview Camera AVFoundation]

**Update to discuss about the mask layers color**

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask) for `mask` defines this behavior that the alpha channel determines what content, if any will be allowed to show.

> **mask**
>
> An optional view whose alpha channel is used to mask a view’s
> content.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The view’s alpha channel determines how much of the view’s
> content and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels
> allow the underlying content to show through but fully transparent
> pixels block that content.

The fill color is **not** the circle color as you rightly pointed out. You could change this and it would not matter as long as it is not clear color. It determines whether the mask renders the underlying view or not.

To actually add some color to this, I believe you cannot do it directly through the mask layer and you would need an intermediary layer.

Comment: Thanks for this Shawn can't understand why the fill color is white ? The fill color is not the circle color then

Comment: @nicover - I updated the answer with some notes from the documentation.

Comment: great thanks again. please one more thing if I want to update the radius value here let say on click/drag I must to re execute all of this code ? or can I update only a part ? for the radius

Comment: I think you can do something with `CABasicAnimation` - some insights here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459532/uiview-layer-mask-animate and it could be a good new question if you are unable to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks.  regarding this question do you know why the stroke color is gone ?

Comment: @nicover - The border works the same as the fill color, that is, anything of the mask that is not transparent will be used to display pixels of the view below it. A quick test you can do is to make your `shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor` clear again and I believe you will see the camera preview in the border only. If you want to add colors or border colors, I believe you will need to add another shape layer in addition to your mask - give it a go, if it is still proving too tricky, maybe open another question.